# Set up a Jupyter remote server, SSH connected to localhost port - how do I open localhost ipynb files in my IDE

Tags: python, ssh, jupyter-notebook

I want to be able to edit my ipynb files in an IDE like VSCode or Pycharm instead of having to open the files using the browser login. Any suggestions?

For clarity:

remotehost:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=####
```

local:

`ssh -N -L ####:localhost:#### me@remotehost`

http://localhost:8899/?token###

All working fine.

Comment: For VSCode, this might be useful https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support

Comment: Ty. Had a look at that before. This is what throws me off: 

"Once you've imported the file, you can run the code as you would with any other Python file and also use the VS Code debugger."

They don't specify how to actually load that file. Do they mean just download a local copy? Or is there a way I can point my IDE to open that file directly. That's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm 2019.1 you can do the following:

1. open the file by double-clicking on it

[image]

2. Click on the + sign, and click on *Insert Code Cell*
   [image]
3. Add code to your cell, and then click on the Play button to run the cell. Select *Run Cell* to execute your code.

[image]

Notice that the result of the execution of your cell will be shown in the right side of the PyCharm window. You can keep adding more cells as shown above.

I really hope this helps.

Comment: Ty! Let's go back to step 1 - how do you load the localhost workspace into your project window?

Comment: @PeptideWitch, well I basically just run the play button, and it was already set. You can click on *MANAGED: HTTP://LOCALHOST...* in order to set up the server.

Comment: @PeptideWitch, what version of Pycharm are you using? You just have to open your notebook.

Comment: @PeptideWitch, this feature was added to PyCharm 2019.1, and you can even debug a cell.

Comment: Yep, Pycharm 2019.1. I can configure the jupyter input to point to http://localhost:PORT. But how do I get the work directory to grab all the pre-existing ipynb files that already live on the localhost:port?

Comment: @PeptideWitch, not sure what you are asking for. I thought opening the files would be enough, so you can just edit them...

Comment: I can't open the files through the IDE, though - that's the thing. I can open up my jupyter notebook through Chrome and use the built-in interface, no problem. But I want to use PyCharm to actually open the files that I already have on this server. What you've shown me how to do is make a new Untitled.ipynb file in another directory that is run through jupyter on localhost.

Comment: @PeptideWitch, what if you try to open the file by running (cmd+shift+O in mac or ctrl+shift+O in Windows/Linux), then look for the file, and open it. If that is not opening. Probably you need to associate the file with a jupyter notebook in the settings.

Comment: The file isn't in a windows explorer directory - it's on my localhost, so I can't access it with the explorer, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191421/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-peptidewitch).